# How to activate phpMyAdmin configuration storage?

Tags: configuration, phpmyadmin, storage, config

In my phpMyAdmin page it displays following error

[image]

When I Click the link it displays following.

[image]

and in the documentation it displays following.

[image]

How to fix the above error?

I did following changes in config.inc.php

[image]

But still the problem remains.

Comment: Please note that requesting for urgency on volunteer-driven sites usually results in your question being downvoted or skipped over - no question is more important than another here.

Comment: Did you also run `create_tables.sql` from the 'sql' folder?